# node.js mysql query & push

Tags: mysql, node.js, push

```
mysql.query('SELECT accountID,userID FROM User WHERE notes = "'+info.uid+'"', function(err, fields) {
        var res = fields[0];
        var acc = res['accountID'];
        var user = res['userID'];
        mysql.query('SELECT accountID,groupID FROM GroupList WHERE accountID = "'+acc+'" AND userID = "'+user+'"', function(err, fields) {
        var res = fields[0];
        var acc = res['accountID'];
        var grouplist = res['groupID']; 
        mysql.query('SELECT accountID,deviceID FROM DeviceList WHERE accountID = "'+acc+'" AND groupID = "'+grouplist+'"', function(err,rows,fields) {
        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        var deviceID = rows[i].deviceID
        mysql.query('SELECT accountID,deviceID,statusCode,longitude,latitude,speedKPH,heading,timestamp FROM EventData WHERE accountID = "'+acc+'" AND deviceID = "'+deviceID+'"  ORDER BY timestamp DESC ',
         function(err,rows,fields) {
         for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
          var deviceID = rows[i].deviceID;
          re2.push({
          title: deviceID,                   
          });
           console.log(re2)
           console.log("====================")
           return next(null,re2)       
             }         
           } 
        )}            
        )}
        )}  
        else{
          next(null, "accountID not register")
        }
```

})
**The above code produces the following output :** 
 
[{titel:device1}] 
==================== 
[{titel:device2}] 
====================
[{titel:device3}] 


**But I expected to see the following:** 

[{titel:device1},
{titel:device2},
{titel:device3}]
====================

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: http://sscce.org/ Emphasis on *short*

Answer (score 0):

```
 mysql.query('SELECT accountID,deviceID,lastBatteryLevel,lastValidLatitude,lastValidLongitude,lastEventTimestamp FROM Device WHERE deviceID in (SELECT deviceID FROM DeviceList WHERE accountID = "'+acc+'" AND groupID = "'+grouplist+'")'
```

is working !
Just add  WHERE deviceID in